# Simple Face Detection Recourses

Tags: face-detection

I am looking for a way to start detecting faces in an image. 
Any recourses that you use or find best for beginners?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally there are at least two approaches.

1. Finding a face based on the color (e.g face color and hair color)
2. Based on characteristics of the face (we have two eyes, and a nose below etc.)

Try [this page](http://www.facedetection.com/facedetection/techniques.htm) that describes basic techniques of face detection